# Appium Inspector Not Starting Session (--allow cors error)

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

When attempting to "Start Session" in Appium Inspector, the following error is displayed:

```
Error
Could not connect to server; are you sure it's running? If you are using the browser version, also ensure your Appium server has been started with --allow-cors.
```

[image]

I am running the desktop version of Appium Server and have set "Allow CORS" to true from the advanced menu.

[image]

The android emulator is running and I have inputted the correct value for udid as shown when entering "adb devices" command in the cmd:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this so that the Appium Inspector works correctly? It seems that Appium Inspector used to be built into the Appium Server application, but is now a separate app.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it worked for me.

I followed the discussion here https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/issues/1927

I entered `127.0.0.1` as a remote host instead of `0.0.0.0` and it got connected

Answer (score 0):

A start to help you out with your problem is to fix your Capabilities. Please remove all *appium:* keywords from your capabilities and have them like this:

```
appPackage: com....
appActivity: com...
platformName: Android
platformVersion: xx
deviceName: emulator-5554
```

Also, remove the *udid* Capability as this is actually the *deviceName*. Everytime you see UDID, you must always think of a 40-digit lowercase hex code or a 25-digit uppercase hex code. At least, not a String.

Comment: It is still not connecting

Comment: @paul try to downgrade to Appium v1.21.0, they have overhauled some things in the newest Appium with regard to drivers. I have not yet dived into this, v1.21.0 might work simplistic in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to input the Report Path with value is /wd/hub